# How to start a Laravel project in CMD via Artsian commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm learning Laravel and they say in order to create a new laravel site you have to make your folders like this:

```
--webshop
  --root
    --laravel (contains the laravel files)
    --assets (contains the css,fonts,img,js from the public folder of laravel)
    --.htaccess
    --favicon.ico
    --index.php
    --robots.txt
    --web.config
```

So as you can see I cut the containers of public folder inside Laravel and paste them in the root directory. So now I want to start the project and make it live on the localhost using Artisan commands but I don't know in which folder I have to make it live... For example root directory or laravel directory inside of root or something else... So can u please help me!

Answer (score 1):

No, that's wrong. install laravel by **composer** like this:

```
composer require --prefer-dist laravel/laravel mysite
```

from inside **mysite** start project by run the artisan command `php artisan serve` and enter in the browser the url `127.0.0.1:8000`

more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Wamp or Xampp if you're on Mac/Linux, it's a PHP local server with phpmyadmin if you want to test out with a local database. Also have you created your project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nameofyourproject`? It installs all the basic folders you need to start using laravel right away, you can then copy those files on Wampp/Lampp and use localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation here:https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

If you have composer installed, use:`composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Now, to create a new project simply run : `laravel new ProjectName`.

No need to create a directory structure on your own.